# How do you add a new field to multiple documents after you have updated the mongoose schema?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

My partner and I have searched everywhere and tried everything with the Mongo documentation to look up how to insert and update new schema and update all of the documents in the database. We did not have any luck. Right now we are trying to add two new fields onto all of the current documents within the database. Both are array fields which we have updated the schema but nothing showing for the documents themselves. ALSO I AM FULLY AWARE there are many questions that are similar but I wanted to see if anyone could figure out our problem since it seems to work for everyone else but not us

- MongoDB documentation
- update, $set and upsert aggregation functions

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Schema for how we define a movie object 

const MovieSchema = new Schema({ 
    id: { 
        type: Number
    },
    title: { 
        type: String
    }, 
    year: { 
        type: Number
    }, 
    rating: { 
        type: String //(PG, PG-13, R, NR, MA)
    }, 
    cast: { 
        type: [String], //Hold multiple cast members based on how many the user types in
        default: undefined
    }, 
    quotes: { 
        type: [String],
        default: undefined
    },
    genres: { 
        type: [String],
        default: undefined
    }, 
    synopsis: { 
        type: String
    }, 
    imageURL: { 
        type: String
    },
    bannerURL: { 
        type: String
    }
})

const Movie = mongoose.model('movies', MovieSchema);

module.exports = Movie;
```

These are the new fields being added to all documents

```
comments:{ 
        type: [String],
        default: undefined
    },
characters: { 
        type: [String]
        default: undefined
}
```

we have done most of the mongo functions through the commandline and prefer to do it that way unless there isn't a way

Comment: just experienced this myself. Let me know if my answer helps you out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already updated your schema to have the two new fields:

```
Movie.find()
   .then((allMovies) => {
       allMovies.forEach((movieSchema) => {
           //create two new fields in each schema
           movieSchema.comments = []
           movieSchema.characters = []
           //save the schema we updated
           movieSchema.save()
       })
   })
   .catch((errors) => {
       return res.status(400).json({ nomoviesfound: "could not find movies"})
   })
```

Comment: Alright so would I put this in the routes folder? I also assume there's no way to do this via the command line?

Comment: You could put this in your index.js file if you'd like, really anywhere that has your Movie model defined. You'll only have to run it once.

Comment: Awesome I will try it now!

Comment: How'd it go? :)

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU SO MUCH! IT WORKED LIKE A CHARM!

Comment: LOL NICE. Yeah I've had that same problem any time I add a new field to my mongoose schema. Just rinse and repeat.

Comment: Now I know what to do everytime we have to update the schema I can not thank you enough!